# How to create Proportional Stacked column?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a script of stacked column and I want to make it proportional every bar with labels inside the bar. How can I can I do that? I try some edits but it's not working. I'm currently using Google Chart. Please help me. Thanks.

Here's the script:

```
function drawVisualization() {

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Year', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Czech Republic', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany'],
['2003',  1336060,   3817614,       974066,       1104797,   6651824,  15727003],
['2004',  1538156,   3968305,       928875,       1151983,   5940129,  17356071],
['2005',  1576579,   4063225,       1063414,      1156441,   5714009,  16716049],
['2006',  1600652,   4604684,       940478,       1167979,   6190532,  18542843],
['2007',  1968113,   4013653,       1037079,      1207029,   6420270,  19564053],
['2008',  1901067,   6792087,       1037327,      1284795,   6240921,  19830493]
]);
var options = {
            title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:1000, height:400,
            isStacked: true,
            hAxis: {title: "Year"}
            };
var chart = new    google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
        chart.draw(data,options);

}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

And what if my data is strings/text? How to put label inside the graph and make it proportional? It is possible?

Example data:

```
['Year', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Germany'],
['2003',  AB,   BA,      CA],
['2004',  AC,   BB,    CB],
['2005',  AD,   BC, CC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DataView to calculate the proportional total for each cell, and create annotations to label the bars:

```
var columns = [0];
for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    // add a column that calculates the proportional value of this column to the total
    columns.push({
        type: 'number',
        label: data.getColumnLabel(i),
        calc: (function (col) {
            return function (dt, row) {
                var val = dt.getValue(row, col);
                var total = 0;
                for (var j = 1; j < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); j++) {
                    total += dt.getValue(row, j);
                }
                return (total == 0) ? null : {v: val / total, f: val.toString()}; 
            };
        })(i)
    });
    // add an annotation column that puts a label on the bar
    columns.push({
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation',
        sourceColumn: i,
        calc: 'stringify'
    });
}

view.setColumns(columns);
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/ukRPd/

Comment: what is the meaning of push? and what if the data is text/strings? it is the same formula?

Comment: other layer of the stacked have no label

Comment: The `push` method is a method of `Array` that adds a new element to the end of the array.  All of the layers of the chart do have annotations, but there may not be sufficient space to display them.  If you increase the height of the chart, you can see them: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/ukRPd/1/

Comment: Ok i see. What if my data is not integer? What if it is text or strings?

Comment: The structure of the code might need to change a bit.  Can you update your question with example data you would like this to work with?

Comment: Your example shows variables in place of data - which values are strings and which are numbers?  Do you intend to use the strings as the labels for the bars, or for something else?

Comment: I want to use strings as a data instead of numbers

Comment: You have to have numbers somewhere, or you can't draw the chart.